# how to format the result with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have the following printout,

```json
{
  "metric": {
    "container": "container1",
    "namespace": "namespace1",
    "pod": "pod1"
  },
  "values": [
    [
      1664418600,
      "1"
    ],
    [
      1664418900,
      "2"
    ],
    [
      1664419200,
      "6"
    ],
    [
      1664419500,
      "8"
    ],
    [
      1664419800,
      "7"
    ],
    [
      1664420100,
      "9"
    ]
  ]
}
{
  "metric": {
    "container": "container2",
    "namespace": "namespace2",
    "pod": "pod2"
  },
  "values": [
    [
      1664420100,
      "1"
    ]
  ]
}
```

What I want:

```
container=container1,namespace=namespace1,pod=pod1
1 1664418600
2 1664418900
6 1664419200
8 1664419500
7 1664419800
9 1664420100
container=container2,namespace=namespace2,pod=pod2
1 1664420100
```

Comment: What did you try and what errors did you run into?

Answer (score 1):

Build it from two JSON programs:

1. Header lines: `.metric | to_entries | map(join("=")) | join(",")`

   1. Get `metric` object: `.metric`
   2. Convert to an array of key-value pairs: `to_entries`
   3. Map each key-value pair object to a string "key=value": `map(join("="))`
   4. Join all pairs by comma: `join(",")`
2. Value lists: `.values[] | [last,first] | join(" ")`

   1. Stream values: `.values[]`
   2. Reverse each two-valued array: `[last,first]`
   3. Join items by blank: `join(" ")`

An alternative for 2.2. and 2.3. could be `"\(last) \(first)"`, i.e. `values[] | "\(last) \(first)"`. Or `[last,first]` could be replaced with `reverse`: `.values[] | reverse | join(" ")`.

Putting the two programs together:

```
(.metric | to_entries | map(join("=")) | join(",")),
(.values[] | [last,first] | join(" "))
```

And then execute with raw output enabled: `jq -r (.metrics|to_entries…`

Output:

```
container=container1,namespace=namespace1,pod=pod1
1 1664418600
2 1664418900
6 1664419200
8 1664419500
7 1664419800
9 1664420100
container=container2,namespace=namespace2,pod=pod2
1 1664420100
```

Comment: If `.metric` and `.values` should be dynamic, `objects` and `arrays` applied to `.[]` may help out: `.[] | (objects | to_entries | map(join("=")) | join(",")), (arrays[] | reverse | join(" "))`